# webdriverio getText method and promises

Tags: webdriver-io, chai-as-promised

hi i am using cucumber with webdriverio (with chai and chai-as-promised) - following test work -

```
browser.getText('#copyright').to.eventually.equal('my text').and.notify(callback),
```

but if i use element like h1 instead of '#copyright' than it does not work, so

```
browser.getText('h1').to.eventually.equal('my text').and.notify(callback)
```

does not work,

but callback return me text if i rewrite test as -

```
browser.getText('h1', function(err, text)
{
       expect(text).to.equal('my test'); 
       callback();
});
```

i wonder what is difference and why second one 'h1' does not work with chai-as-promised' thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't work, because h1 is an element selector, but #copyright is an ID selector.

I'd assume, that getText('h1') returns an array, and getText('#copyright') = single element.